# PyMongo: Cannot call map_reduce on dict object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am following an example on calling map_reduce as you can see below.

```
result = db.things.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresults")
```

I get following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-112-c1ea3f3df4bb> in <module>()
----> 1 result = db.things.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresults")

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'map_reduce'
```

What am I doing wrong?

The example is from here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html

Comment: Could you be more specific with mapper and reducer?

Comment: I don't think the error is related to mapper and reduce function. I am running an example from here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html

Comment: I have tested the example with no problem. I guess there are two possibilities here: 1 you assign a dict to db.things 2 mapper and reducer are unsuitable.

Comment: 1. db.things is not a dic, but it returns a data structure of type dict 2. What do you mean by mapper and reducer are unsuitable?

Comment: ----> 1 result = db.things.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "myresults")

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'map_reduce' 
That is why it is suspicious.

Comment: And I told you the official example has no problem. why are you asking what are you doing wrong without telling what are you doing?

Comment: Check your version of the driver as well. What version are you using? The example is for 2.0.